# Unable to install the rtl8188fu wifi adapter driver on my Jetson Nano 4GB

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

So I have a USB WiFi Dongle and I need the drivers for it (0bda:f179), ie, rtl8188fu.
I am currently trying to use it on my Jetson Nano 4GB and I found this tutorial for it:https://github.com/corneal64/Realtek-USB-Wireless-Adapter-Drivers/tree/ARM-driver
which isnt working as I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.9.337-tegra (aarch64)
```

I can solve the apt_pkg error by switching to python 3.6 but the bad return status doesn't seem to go away.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; Jetson Nano's usually use a OS created by Nvidia that contains parts from Ubuntu and parts from Debian, and are not Ubuntu products.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Your kernel version shows a non-Ubuntu kernel, and python3 version detail does not match any supported version of Ubuntu either*

Answer (score 0):

Try [THIS](https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu) Repo.

1. Install required packages for rtl8188fu Wi-Fi driver: `sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms`
2. Clone rtl8188fu Wi-Fi driver: `git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu`

You can skip below step if you are not worried about kernel logs

3. To minimize dmesg logging, edit `sudo vi rtl8188fu/include/autoconf.h` and comment the following lines

```
#define CONFIG\_DEBUG /\* DBG\_871X, etc... \*
#define CONFIG\_PROC\_DEBUG
```

4. Install the driver: `sudo dkms install ./rtl8188fu` and copy firmware: `sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/`
5. Restart the device: `sudo reboot.`

Upon successful installation of the driver, the `wlan0` Wi-Fi interface should be available.

To solve this problem Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.253-tegra you can install headers using sudo apt-get install linux-headers-nvidia-tegra.

The driver installing works without installing these headers too.

Hope this helps!